# EF6 stored procedure with no results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

My environment is VS 2012, C#, EF6 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to execute a stored procedure to delete records with no return value using the pattern:

```
dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<return type>("name", parameter)
```

If there are no results returned e.g. with `NO COUNT ON` what should I set as the return type? Seems that it should be simple but I cannot find an answer anywhere.

I tried `dataContext.Database.SqlQuery("name", parameter)` but that returns a compile error:
The best overloaded method match for `'System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery(System.Type, string, params object[])'` has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) instead of [`SqlQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) if you don't need to query some data:

```
dataContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("name", parameter)
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but I get a compile error The best overloaded method match for `'System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery(System.Type, string, params object[])'` has some invalid arguments. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: @PeterSmith sorry, didn't get why you are still trying to use your original code instead of code from my answer

Comment: ExecuteSqlCommand is right. You have to check the way you are filling the parameters and if you are including parameters in stored procedure name parameter

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I tried to use your code but I got a compile error. See edited answer above. Thanks

Comment: @Alberto Please see question - I am trying to NOT specify a return type parameter.

Comment: @PeterSmith error above says that you haven't tried to use my code. You are still trying to execute `SqlQuery` method.