# The data reader has more than one field error while calling a procedure that returns an integer

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I was trying to get status code of a stored procedure execution when encountered this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I have rewritten the procedure to do absolutely nothing but to return an integer value, this is how it looks now:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[test]
(
    @i int,
    @a nvarchar(max),
    @b nvarchar(max),
    @c nvarchar(max),
    @d nvarchar(max)
)
As
Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    return 1
End
```

But I still get the same error at run-time when reaching the procedure call at line:

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<int>("test @i, @a, @b, @c, @d", p_i, p_a, p_b, p_c, p_d).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there anyway to figure out what these fields are, and where they are coming from? And how should I get the returned value?

I've tried to specify a tuple of two strings as the `T` just to look into these values, but with no success...

**Updates:**
`Select 1` instead of `return 1` makes the function usable, the only question remains what are these mysterious fields that are returned to the data reader?

Comment: try with `select 1` instead of return.

Comment: The code that you are showing is calling a different stored proc than the one that you have modified, which could potentially explain the issue (unless there was a typo in the post).

Comment: @competent_tech Sorry, it's the name of the original function which was simplified, it's just a typo in the post...

Answer (score 9):

`Database.SqlQuery<T>()` expects some kind of result set (e.g. `SELECT`). Under the hood, it uses [`DbCommand.ExecuteReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc093a69(v=vs.110).aspx), and when `T` is scalar, it expects the result set to have exactly one field -- but if the result set has more than one field, *or if there are no fields*, it throws the exception that you encountered.

The return value can be retrieved by passing a `DbParameter` to [`Database.SqlQuery<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) and setting [`Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection(v=vs.110).aspx) as seen in these examples:

- [How can I get return value of stored procedure when using SqlDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093317/how-can-i-get-return-value-of-stored-procedure-when-using-sqldatareader)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/10/how-to-execute-stored-procedures-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api.aspx

---

FYI, if you just want the return value, but you don't want a result set, use [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456(v=vs.113).aspx) with a `DbParameter`.

- [EF6 stored procedure with no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043585/ef6-stored-procedure-with-no-results)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about the behind the scenes stuff, but I didn't get the point, the procedure returns exactly one value, I'm not sure that it can be thought of as a field though, but the message says that the reader has more than one field...

Comment: @Jyrkka: What I mean to say is that when using `SqlQuery`, it counts fields in the result set, so `SELECT x, y, FROM table` would have two fields. When `T` is a scalar, it expects one field, but if there are no fields, it looks like it gives the same error as when there are more than one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var result = this.Database.SqlQuery<int>("exec test {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", p_i, p_a, p_b, p_c, p_d).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: when are you getting that error on compile or runtime ? i think it should work. Also try "exec [dbo].[test] {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}"

Comment: Have tried also the second one, the error remained the same, I'm getting it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer given by Charlie is right. But you have to write the code as follows.

```
var result = this.Database.SqlQuery<int>(string.Format("exec test {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", p_i, p_a, p_b, p_c, p_d)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Well, now the exception is different `Error converting data type nvarchar to int.`

Comment: the statement is right. so check the datatype of the parameters within the stored procedure and the values you are passing to them.

Comment: I can run the query from the SSMS, thus both the procedure and the values are usable. The only thing I can think of is that you need to put quotes around {1-4}, since  @a, @b, @c and @d are nvarchars...

Answer (score 0):

I came to a similar situation, I was calling a procedure from EF and the procedure had some print statements, EF was getting confused as it reads all the prints as an output. Make sure you comment all the prints before using it in EF.

Comment: Well, as you can see it is completely different story - look at the query, there are no print statements - only one simple `return`...